# Encrypted Users Directory

Tags: encryption, network-user

This is the scenario:

I have some macbooks bound to Active Directory, so that any AD user can log in. Per requirements from above, all user data needs to be encrypted. Encrypting the **entire** hard drive proves to be problematic because it prevents authentication against AD when the laptop just boots up.

Is there a away to put the entire /Users directory on an encrypted partition so that a user can log in and then decrypt the Users partition?

Comment: This seems problematic. What's the use case and/or your expectations? OS X needs the /User folder to be readable before users log in so that cart is before the horse so to speak...

Comment: This use case is that some of our users save sensitive information to their users home directory. Keeping those encrypted will help us keep that information secure.

Comment: Why not use FileVault to encrypt the entire drive? If you have multiple users, you can then have them make encrypted disk images for specially compartmented information that's not already safe enough to have user account separation of privileges. I know of many organizations that use FileVault and AD, so perhaps just fixing that would work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more googling, I found what I was looking for:

https://github.com/jridgewell/Unlock

> Description
>
> Unlock allows the system to unlock and mount Core Storage encrypted
>   volumes during boot. In other words, this allows you to log in as a
>   user whose home directory is on an encrypted secondary disk without
>   any problems.